# QWidget can we get/modify existing context menu of a widget

Tags: qt, qt4

I have third party widget which provides me some context menu. Lets say cut, copy paste, select all.
Now I just want to modify only the paste functionality of the existing context menu. I know that I can implement whole context menu from scratch in the `contextMenuEvent`. But I do not want to do that as I am satisfied with other context menu actions, and just want to modify only the paste functionality.

I am using QT 4.8 on Mac OSX.

If such a thing is not possible at the moment can someone give me link/reference for that ? So that I can satisfy my stakeholders.

Edit: To be more clearer on what I am trying to do is, disable the paste context menu for some reason, and want to enable it later on depending on the situation/events.

Comment: Take a look at the decorator pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: just to ensure: is your 3rd party widget a `QWidget`,i.e. is it written on `Qt` ?

Comment: @Ezee: yes definitely, I have seen the header files. Top level class is inherited from QWidget.

Comment: @Merlin069: I have already subclass the third party class. Problem is that in contextMenuEvent, I can create whole context menu from scratch, but I do not know how to get/modify existing context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it can be done in a common way.
Here is a tricky solution:

In `contextMenuEvent` create a queued call to some slot:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "patchMenu", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Get visible windows in the slot and find `QMenu`. Get actions out of it and enable/disable them:

```
Q_SLOT patchMenu()
{
  QWidgetList widgets = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
  foreach (QWidget* widget, widgets)
  {
    if (QMenu* menu = qobject_cast<QMenu*>(widget))
    {
        QList<QAction*> actions = menu->actions();
        // here you can either get an action by index actions[5]
        // or search the action by text
        actions;
    }
  } 
}
```

EDIT:
Here is a **working example** which demonstrates this approach:
window.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QtGui>

class Window: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

class A : public QWidget
{
public:
    virtual void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* e);
};

class B : public A
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    virtual void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*);

    Q_SLOT void patchMenu();
};
```

window.cpp

```
#include "window.h"

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setCentralWidget(new B());
}

void B::patchMenu()
{
    QWidgetList widgets = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
    foreach (QWidget* widget, widgets)
    {
        if (QMenu* menu = qobject_cast<QMenu*>(widget))
        {
            QList<QAction*> actions = menu->actions();
            // here you can either get an action by index actions[5]
            // or search the action by text
            actions;
        }
    }   
}

void B::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* e)
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "patchMenu", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    A::contextMenuEvent(e);
}

void A::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* e)
{
    QMenu menu;
    QAction* action = new QAction(QIcon(), "text", &menu);
    menu.addAction(action);
    menu.exec(e->globalPos());
}
```

Comment: I have applied the above code and print out the action text and shortcuts. This workaround showed me each action for each widget but unfortunately context menu actions was not there. Nonetheless +1 for the workaround.

Comment: Added an example which you can run and ensure that it works. You couldn't get actions of each widget because it filters out everything except `QMenu`.

Comment: yes, by each action of each widget I mean QMenu actions. I've compared your code with mine. The only logical difference was the order of Base class contextMenuEvent call. I was calling A::contextMenuEvent(e) first and then QMetaObject::invokeMethod(...). Now I applied it in your way and I can see the list of context menu actions. Thanx buddy :). But One more curious question is it the proper way of doing this ? I mean to disable one action you have to go through all the widgets and their actions.

Comment: It's not a problem to "go through" but supposing that the base widget doesn't re-create actions every time it shows the menu, you can store a pointer to the action you need when you found it the first time and then use this pointer to enable/disable the action. But if it does recreate actions every time, you'll get a crash using the pointer.

Comment: Well said, I got it. Unfortunately I don't have the source code of top base class. So I'll have to do hit and try, and apply the solution most suitable for me. Thanx again for helping me out, accepting your solution. Thumbs up.